# If I update vim, will I have to configure .vimrc again?

Tags: vim

If I update vim, will I have to configure .vimrc again?
I have installed conquer on completion(coc) on vim version 8.1 but it requires vim version greater than 8.1
to work properly.

I'm afraid of losing my configurations.

Comment: It depends on where you made your configuration. If it is in your `$HOME` (`~/.vim/`, `~/.vimc`, etc.), then you are fine.

Comment: I did the update and everything is fine as you said. Thank you.